# Is it possible to serialize/deserialize an enumeration?

Tags: scala

Say I define the following:

```
object Numbers extends Enumeration {
  val One = Value(1)
  val Two = Value(2)
  val Three = Value(3)
}
```

I want to be able to store this value (ideally as a string but an Int would do). Suppose I do the following:

```
    val x = Test.Two
    val s = x.toString
    val i = x.id
```

Then would there be a way I could restore this value?

```
val y = ??? // Restore from either s or i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use withName function

```
object Numbers extends Enumeration {
  val One = Value(1)
  val Two = Value(2)
  val Three = Value(3)
}

val name = Numbers.Two.toString
val restoredValue = Numbers.withName(name)
```

but it's not gonna work if values have String type...another way is through id

```
val saved = Numbers.Two.id
val list = Numbers.values.toArray
val restored = list(saved)
```